# Ubuntu broken, deleted system file libboost_system.so1.58.0

Tags: 16.04, data-recovery

I have 16.04. Writing from my phone. I was trying to manually remove Boost and doing something like rm *boost* and accidentally removed some system files.

Currently have two open terminals, can't open anything more.

But the error I get if I try to open stuff like Firefox or terminal from the terminal is:

error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.58.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

If I try to sudo apt-get the file it says it already exists.

I have also tried doing lsof | grep "filename" but get only PID USR and instead of the file id i get DEL, so I guess this is not an option (I've read this in another post about recovering files).

Is there anything I can do besides reinstalling ubuntu?

Comment: Try to run `sudo apt install --reinstall libboost-system1.58.0`, this will reinstall the mentioned file. But we don't know if you removed other system files as well, so this command may solve only a part of the problem.

Comment: It didn't work. The package was reinstalled but I still get the same error. Thanks